# The instantiation of the template class is wrong

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

The g++ compiler prompt the following statement is wrong:

```
template<typename Type>
class SingleList{
public:
    SingleList()
        {
            head =  new SingleListNode<Type> () ;    //Error happens here!!!
        }
```

The error message is :

```
 ./inc/single_list.h: In instantiation of ‘SingleListNode<int>’:
./inc/single_list.h|39 col 13| instantiated from ‘SingleList<Type>::SingleList() [with Type = int]’
```

The definition of `head` is the following, maybe problem is not related here.

```
SingleListNode<Type> *head;
```

The instantiation of class `SingleList` in `main` function is :

```
int main()
{
    SingleList<int> list;
```

I don't know where the syntax error happens, can anyone help me? Thanks!!

========================================================================

The following is the content of source file:

```
    template<typename Type> class SingleList;

template<typename Type> class SingleListNode{
private:
    friend class SingleList<Type>;

    SingleListNode() : next(NULL){}

public:
    friend ostream& operator<< <Type>(ostream& os,SingleListNode<Type>& sln);             //Error here!!

private:
    SingleListNode *next;
};

template<typename Type> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,SingleListNode<Type>& out){
    os<<out.data;
    return os;
}

template<typename Type> class SingleList{
public:
    SingleList()
        {
            head =  new SingleListNode<Type> () ;              //Error happens here.
        }
    ~SingleList(){
        delete head;                                       //Same error
    }

private:
    SingleListNode<Type> *head;
};
```

The error message prompted by g++

```
|| g++ -g -I ./inc/ -c single_list_test.cpp  -o single_list_test.o
|| single_list.h: In instantiation of ‘SingleListNode<int>’:
single_list.h|25 col 13| instantiated from ‘SingleList<Type>::SingleList() [with Type = int]’
single_list_test.cpp|9 col 18| instantiated from here
single_list.h|10 col 18| error: template-id ‘operator<< <int>’ for ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, SingleListNode<int>&)’ does not match any template declaration
|| make: *** [single_list_test.o] Error 1
```

Comment: That isn’t the error message, it just tells us *where* the error is (context), not *what* it is. Furthermore, it would help if you posted a *complete*, *minimal* code to showcase the problem. Highly incomplete code fragments like this obscure more than they help us.

Comment: Thanks, I add the complete code.

Comment: You missed that I said to post “minimal” code. This code isn’t minimal, it contains plenty of stuff that’s irrelevant to the problem. You also still didn’t post the error message, and I suspect that you posted the wrong code since the error does *not* happen where you say it does.

Comment: Now I think the code is minimal, and easy to test. I can't minimize it anymore.  Just two files, and structure is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my gcc , just modify the following statement

```
friend ostream& operator<< <Type>(ostream& os,SingleListNode<Type>& sln)
```

to

```
 friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,SingleListNode<Type>& sln)
```